# text not showing on bitmap image in C#

Tags: c#, image, text

I can't seem to get the text I've written to show up on my image Here's the code I'm using

```
//Creates a bitmap with the path to the current image
Bitmap LabelImage = new Bitmap(dtImages.Rows[intCurrentImage]["ImageURL"].ToString());

Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(LabelImage);

graphic.DrawString("Hello", new Font("Tahoma",40), Brushes.Azure, new System.Drawing.Point(0,0));

//put Image that I just created and put the text on into an Infragistics UltraPicureBox
picImage.Image = LabelImage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this

```
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\Untitled.png");
 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
 g.DrawString("Hello", new Font("Tahoma", 40), Brushes.Azure, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
 pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

and it works fine for me. Just try to pick a contrasting brush.

Answer (score 4):

You did not update your original image (`LabelImage`), so why should the text you added to the `Graphics` object show up?.

From MSDN, [`Graphics.FromImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx):

> Creates a **new** Graphics from the specified Image.

(emphasis mine)

After you have added the text, you need to save the changes:

```
graphic.Save();
```

---

Unrelated to your question, you should really put the creation of the `Graphics` object in a `using` statement, to ensure proper disposal:

```
using(Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(LabelImage))
{
   // use graphic here
}
```